# Helidon override libs folder

Tags: classpath, libs, helidon

Is it possible to override the libs folder in helidon project? I want to copy jars to classpath at runtime. I was able to use -Dweblogic.ext.dirs to do that in weblogic server.

Answer (score 1):

Helidon isn't an application server, so it just works with the regular Java classpath.  As with any Java program, once the classpath is set, it's set.  Helidon does not use multiple classloaders, so there's no runtime deploying or anything like that.  (You are, of course, free to create your own classloaders or whatever you want since it's just Java.)

So: set up your classpath the way you want, and start your Java program that uses Helidon libraries.